# Name Value Pair Table to Columns

Tags: mysql

I've been racking my head over this in MYSQL, since there are no Pivots or Cubes.
I have tried using Case When and it partly works however I can't seem to filter it for only Member=Yes, despite the subquery working to filter out the 'No'

```
CREATE TABLE `nvp` (
`rowid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`groupid` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`value` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`created` date DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`rowid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `t2`.`nvp` (`groupid`, `name`, `value`, `created`) VALUES ('1', 'Fee', '10', '2014-03-01');  
INSERT INTO `t2`.`nvp` (`groupid`, `name`, `value`, `created`) VALUES ('1', 'Member', 'Yes', '2014-03-01');  
INSERT INTO `t2`.`nvp` (`groupid`, `name`, `value`, `created`) VALUES ('1', 'Type', 'MLB', '2014-03-01');  
INSERT INTO `t2`.`nvp` (`groupid`, `name`, `value`, `created`) VALUES ('2', 'Fee', '10', '2014-03-01');  
INSERT INTO `t2`.`nvp` (`groupid`, `name`, `value`, `created`) VALUES ('2', 'Member', 'Yes', '2014-03-01');  
INSERT INTO `t2`.`nvp` (`groupid`, `name`, `value`, `created`) VALUES ('2', 'Type', 'MLB', '2014-03-01');  
INSERT INTO `t2`.`nvp` (`groupid`, `name`, `value`, `created`) VALUES ('3', 'Fee', '10', '2014-03-02');  
INSERT INTO `t2`.`nvp` (`groupid`, `name`, `value`, `created`) VALUES ('3', 'Member', 'Yes', '2014-03-02');  
INSERT INTO `t2`.`nvp` (`groupid`, `name`, `value`, `created`) VALUES ('3', 'Type', 'MLB', '2014-03-02');  
INSERT INTO `t2`.`nvp` (`groupid`, `name`, `value`, `created`) VALUES ('4', 'Fee', '20', '2014-03-03');  
INSERT INTO `t2`.`nvp` (`groupid`, `name`, `value`, `created`) VALUES ('4', 'Member', 'Yes', '2014-03-03');  
INSERT INTO `t2`.`nvp` (`groupid`, `name`, `value`, `created`) VALUES ('4', 'Type', 'NFL', '2014-03-03');  
INSERT INTO `t2`.`nvp` (`groupid`, `name`, `value`, `created`) VALUES ('5', 'Fee', '50', '2014-03-03');  
INSERT INTO `t2`.`nvp` (`groupid`, `name`, `value`, `created`) VALUES ('5', 'Member', 'Yes', '2014-03-03');   
INSERT INTO `t2`.`nvp` (`groupid`, `name`, `value`, `created`) VALUES ('5', 'Type', 'NBA', '2014-03-03');  
INSERT INTO `t2`.`nvp` (`groupid`, `name`, `value`, `created`) VALUES ('6', 'Fee', '50', '2014-03-03');  
INSERT INTO `t2`.`nvp` (`groupid`, `name`, `value`, `created`) VALUES ('6', 'Member', 'Yes', '2014-03-03');    
INSERT INTO `t2`.`nvp` (`groupid`, `name`, `value`, `created`) VALUES ('6', 'Type', 'NBA', '2014-03-03');  
INSERT INTO `t2`.`nvp` (`groupid`, `name`, `value`, `created`) VALUES ('7', 'Fee', '100', '2014-03-04');  
INSERT INTO `t2`.`nvp` (`groupid`, `name`, `value`, `created`) VALUES ('7', 'Member', 'No', '2014-03-04');  
INSERT INTO `t2`.`nvp` (`groupid`, `name`, `value`, `created`) VALUES ('7', 'Type', 'NBA', '2014-03-04');
```

Desired output "Pivot" table, **filtered showing only Members** and the sum of each fee collected, grouped by date.

```
Date,      MLB,  NFL, NBA
2014-03-01, 20,   0,   0
2014-03-02, 10,   0,   0
3014-03-03, 0,    20,  50
```

Anyone have some pointers?
Thank you.

This is the SQL tried:

```
select tbl2.created,
    sum(case when tbl2.type='MLB' then fee else null end) as MLB,
    sum(case when tbl2.type='NBA' then fee else null end) as NBA,
    sum(case when tbl2.type='NFL' then fee else null end) as NFL
from (select  tbl.* from (select
    created,
    sum(case when nvp.name='Fee' then value else null end) as  Fee,
    max(case when nvp.name='Type' then value else null end) as  Type,
    max(case when nvp.name='Member'  then value else null end) as  member
from nvp group by groupid) AS tbl where member='Yes') as tbl2 group by created;

# query to transpose row/columns, uses max where strings are required, this does filter out the No.
(select  tbl.* from (select
    created,
    sum(case when nvp.name='Fee' then value else null end) as  Fee,
    max(case when nvp.name='Type' then value else null end) as  Type,
    max(case when nvp.name='Member'  then value else null end) as  member
from nvp group by groupid) AS tbl where member='Yes');
```

Comment: Please show the query that you have attempted.

Comment: What about giving it a try? Just google for examples and try it yourself.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff   I added my sql to the post, thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the basic query that does the total summary:

```
select t.created,
       sum(case when t.type = 'MLB' then fee else null end) as MLB,
       sum(case when t.type = 'NBA' then fee else null end) as NBA,
       sum(case when t.type = 'NFL' then fee else null end) as NFL
from (select created,
             sum(case when nvp.name = 'Fee' then value+0 else null end) as  Fee,
             max(case when nvp.name = 'Type' then value else null end) as  Type,
             max(case when nvp.name = 'Member' then value else null end) as  member
      from nvp
      group by groupid
     ) t
group by created;
```

Adding `where member = 'Yes'` should work:

```
select t.created,
       sum(case when t.type = 'MLB' then fee else null end) as MLB,
       sum(case when t.type = 'NBA' then fee else null end) as NBA,
       sum(case when t.type = 'NFL' then fee else null end) as NFL
from (select created,
             sum(case when nvp.name = 'Fee' then value+0 else null end) as  Fee,
             max(case when nvp.name = 'Type' then value else null end) as  Type,
             max(case when nvp.name = 'Member' then value else null end) as  member
      from nvp
      group by groupid
     ) t
where member = 'Yes'
group by created;
```

And, in fact it does, according to SQL Fiddle (see [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dc1cf/2)).  This looks to be essentially the same as what you tried.

Comment: The issue was me, user-error, thinking that certain data was showing up that should not have been.